# Iterate recursively on an object and append parents to each child

Tags: javascript, templates, object, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a simple template manager for my app. The idea is that all templates will be listed in a multi-dimensional object / array and then each of them will be parsed by some function. Here's what my template object looks like:

```
var tpls = {
    home: 'home',
    about: 'about',
    shop: {
        basket: 'basket',
        checkout: {
            paypal: 'paypal',
            sagepay: 'sagepay',
        }
    },
    user: {
        profile: 'profile',
        settings: 'settings',
    }
};
```

And here's the function I've written so far:

```
function listTemplates(o, parent, templates) {
    var templates = templates || [];

    _.each(o, function (v, k, l) {
        if (Object.keys(v).length > 0 && typeof v === 'object') {
            listTemplates(v, k, templates);
        } else if (typeof v === 'string') {
            var n = (typeof parent === 'string') ? parent + '/' + k : k;
            templates.push(n);
        }
    });

    return templates;
};
```

It does what I want it to do, however I am struggling to figure out how can I append nested parent names to the final output, to achieve the following array:

```
["home", "about", "shop/basket", "shop/checkout/paypal", "shop/checkout/sagepay", "user/profile", "user/settings"]
```

Currently, the function outputs nested templates without their top-level parents, like so:

```
["home", "about", "shop/basket", "checkout/paypal", "checkout/sagepay", "user/profile", "user/settings"]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the parent in your first if condition:

```
if( Object.keys( v ).length > 0 && typeof v === 'object' ) {
    var n = ( typeof parent === 'string' ) ? parent + '/' + k : k;
    listTemplates( v, n, templates );
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vt0oL8d5/ outputs:

```
["home", "about", "shop/basket", "shop/checkout/paypal", "shop/checkout/sagepay", "user/profile", "user/settings"]
```

Comment: holy guacamole! this works. do you mind explaining a bit more WHY should i pass it in the first condition too? it seems i've always struggled with recursion...

Comment: The `parent` holds the absolute path to the child. In your code you are only sending the current parent, which would be `checkout`for `paypal` without sending the parent of checkout, which would be `shop`. So when you loop over the children in checkout, the parent needs to be `shop/checkout` and not only `checkout`.

Comment: No problem. Glad that my explaination wasn't too hard to understand, haha.

Comment: yup, sometimes staring at the same piece of code for too long dumbs me down :)